# Laravel proper approach to multiple hasOne for same model

Tags: php, orm, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a `carriages` table with the following architecture:

```
foreign: subsidiary_id
string: type
string: postal_code
```

And a `subsidiaries` table, with the following architecture:

```
string: name
string: internal_reference
decimal: expedition_rate
```

Now, I am about to adapt my **store** function in **SubsidiariesController** so that it will automatically create 2 carriages for that new subsidiary.

I know, I can very easily go for individual creation steps after the subsidiary has been created, but I was wondering, how a Relationships way could be used?

What I know, is that in my `Subsidiary.php` **model** I can create 2 functions like so:

```
public function carriageExport()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Carriage');
}

public function carriageImport()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Carriage');
}
```

Where `carriageExport` will be a `carriages.type = 'export'`, and `carriageImport` will be a `carriages.type = 'import'`

So,

1. I can't figure out, if defining the relational function, has been done properly. What do you think? I'm missing something, right? What is it?
2. Would you rather stick for the non-relational version?

Answer (score 3):

Scopes are the way to go in this case:

```
class Subsidiary extends Eloquent {

    public function carriage()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Carriage');
    }

}

class Carriage extends Eloquent {

    public function scopeImport($query)
    {
        return $query->whereType('import');
    }

    public function scopeExport($query)
    {
        return $query->whereType('export');
    }

}
```

Then you can:

```
echo Subsidiary::find(1)->carriage()->import()->first()->postal_code;
```